# Getting Mobile Info connected in network using Python Nmap

Tags: python, networking, nmap

I am a beginner to Nmap. I am using python-nmap in Ubunutu 12.04 using Python 2.7.5
I have tried following strategy to get the total number devices using python-nmap

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
data = nm.scan(hosts="192.168.2.1/24", arguments="-sP")
print data['nmap']['scanstats']['uphosts']
```

The above program just gives the total number of devices out of 256 only. Here's a problem too. What should be the IP format if the devices can exceed 256 since /24 is checking upto 256 only?

I tried adding **arguments="-O"** in above program, thus the same code requires sudo previleges, making me to run the program as **sudo python device.py** .

Is there any way in nmap that can identify only mobile devices connected in network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results are in `data['scan']`. If you want to get the list of the IP addresses seen as "up", try this:

```
[ip for ip, result in data['scan'].iteritems() if result['status']['state'] == 'up']
```